# Is it possible to undecorate the web browser?

Tags: java, swing, browser, html

I am trying to play a youTube video in Java and all i want the Frame of the browser to be undecorated just like we have options to undecorate a JFrame or other similar `UI`component by using `setUndecorated(true)`.
I am using:

```
Process p=Runtime.getRuntime().exec("cmd /c start http://www.youtube/foo vide/...");
```

to open a web page. Any suggestions?

Comment: This seems a rather odd way to do things; firstly, you can't make a random window on the system act like a Swing window; secondly, there's no reliable way to determine the "main" window a process spawns; thirdly, there's no reliable way to determine and modify the window before it even first paints; and lastly, the command being used is extremely platform- and configuration-specific. I suggest you search for a Java-based solution to viewing SWFs (though I doubt there would be a cross-platform approach to that)

Comment: @Score_Under A Java-based youtube player should suffice. You don't need a full-blown SWF player.

Comment: @Score_Under well i thought that way because it would be little presentable.Well I never said I want it to act like a Swing window,and its just about the property stuff to make it undecorated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Instead of trying to launch an external browser, you could use a library such as JBrowser. It provides a Java Swing component based on the Mozilla Embedded API.

I used it in the past with good results. You can find it at http://code.google.com/p/jbrowser/

Comment: Then is it possible to undecorate JBrowser?

Comment: +1 Its good..:) but slow :( 
yeah..can be undecorated...thank you:)
any other suggestion?

Comment: Alternatively, have a look DJ: http://djproject.sourceforge.net/ns/index.html. I have never tried it myself though. The only other option I can think of (if you're running Windows) is to use a Java-to-COM bridge to instantiate an Internet Explorer control. I can also control decoration, but it will be less portable.

Comment: Finally, i am using the DJ Project,its wonderful.We can modify the swing components,even what I relly wanted,to undecorate it.
thanks to @Nuno Guerreiro